# CSS transition not working on any properties

Tags: css, angularjs, sass

In my AngularJS app I display a panel once user submits a value in an input field, an when they do, an `active` class is added to the container. When this happens numerous CSS properties are added. I have added the `transition property to apply to both`opacity`and`background`though it isn't applying the`transition` values and just immediately changes.

**.scss file**

```
.container-add-patent {
    .add-patent-panel {
        .found-patent-panel {
                opacity: 0;
                background: green;
                -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 10s;
                -o-transition: all ease-in-out 10s;
                -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 10s;
                transition: all ease-in-out 10s;

        }
    }
    &.active {
        .add-patent-panel {
            .found-patent-panel {
                    background: red;
                    opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*view*

```
<div class="container-add-patent" data-ng-class="{'active': foundPatent}">
    <div class="add-patent-panel" role="dialog">
        <div class="row found-patent-panel" data-ng-show="foundPatent">
            //CONTENT 
        </div>
    </div>
 </div
```

Comment: Sorry that was a paste issue

Comment: Literally just worked it out. It is to do with `data-ng-show`. When I removed it it worked. Looking into why now

Comment: probably because it goes from display none to block and you can't animate that (and it will cause your other animations not to work)

Comment: Maybe add css selector and change the value of `ng-show` class `display:none` and add `opacity:0`?

Comment: AngularJS needs special animation code on it's own, that's why it's not working with css. https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was down to using `ng-show` which applies a property of `display: none` which Pete stated. It's the classes that Angular applies when a directive such as `ng-show` or `ng-if` apply when a boolean value is returned.

If false, `ngIf` results in the element being entirely removed from the DOM. Using the correct selectors, you can target the element when it enters and for the transition of fading in I could use `opacity`. `ngShow` default css property is `display: none` which you can't transition. Below are the changes I made:

```
<div class="container-add-patent" data-ng-class="{'active': foundPatent}">
    <div class="add-patent-panel" role="dialog">
        <div class="row found-patent-panel" data-ng-if="foundPatent"> //changed to `ngIf`
            //CONTENT 
        </div>
    </div>
 </div
```

```
.container-add-patent {
    &.active {
        .add-patent-panel {
            .found-patent-panel {
                &.ng-enter { //classes applied by angular

                    opacity: 0;
                    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out .25s .3s; //Added a delay of .3s
                    -o-transition: all ease-in-out .25s .3s;
                    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .25s .3s;
                    transition: all ease-in-out .25s .3s;
                }
                &.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
                  opacity:1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```